# My code is not printing the customer's list when I use __repr___ in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't want to confuse anyone with this question but I will try my best to write it.

As from my previous questions, I am writing a text adventure game where a customers order a pizza and you make it for them. If you get all of the toppings correct the customer will be satisfied and you go to the next level.

I was messing around with the **repr** to change how the customer's **customerdir** prints instead of it showing brackets. The **customerdir** is a list of toppings that the customer wants on the pizza. When the player makes the pizza the toppings go into the player's **last.pizza** list. If the **last.pizza** list is equal to the **customerdir** then the player made the order right and goes on to the next level.

Everything was going great but now when I execute the code every customer wants Pineapples and Ham. Which is wrong because every customer has their own **customerdir** list with the topping that they want.

See:

```
customer1 = Customer("Jerry", "43 Munan Road", ['Sausages', 'Pepperoni', 'Sliced'].sort())
customer2 = Customer('Mike', "302 Anerley Court", ['Cheese', 'Sliced'].sort())
customer3 = Customer("Lucas", "721 Golf Road", ['Pineapples', 'Ham', 'Not Sliced'].sort())
customer4 = Customer("Tom", "93 Posh Road", ['Sausages', 'Pepperoni', 'Sliced'].sort())
customer5 = Customer('Freddy', "131 Marlon Road", ['Cheese', 'Sliced'].sort())
customer6 = Customer("Arnold", "500 Beach Street", ['Pineapples', 'Ham', 'Not Sliced'].sort())
customer7 = Customer("Lisa", "22 Payton Circle", ['Sausages', 'Pepperoni', 'Sliced'].sort())
customer8 = Customer('Kelly', "Flat A Dustin Court", ['Cheese', 'Sliced'].sort())
customer9 = Customer("Analiese", "90 Simpson Road", ['Pineapples', 'Ham', 'Not Sliced'].sort())
```

Heres the Customer Class:

```
    class Customer:
        def __init__(self, name, address, customerdir):
            self.name = name
            self.address = address
            self.customerdir = customerdir
    
        def __repr__(self):
            if str(self.customerdir == ['Pineapples', 'Ham', 'Not Sliced']):
                return 'Pineapple and Ham Pizza. The customer does not want the pizza to be sliced.'
            elif str(self.customerdir == ['Sausages', 'Pepperoni', 'Sliced']):
                return 'Sausage and Pepperoni Pizza that is sliced.'
            elif str(self.customerdir == ['Cheese', 'Sliced']):
                return 'Cheese Pizza that is sliced.'
```

Here is part of the making_pizza method where the boss tells me that a customer wants a pizza. As you can see I used str(self) instead of str(self.customerdir) so that the print function can print what I put in the **repr**. I tried (self.customerdir) but it just prints out **None**.

```
 print("Joe:" + mPlayer.name + " We have a customer by the name of " + str(self.name))
            time.sleep(a)
            print("Joe: He would like a " + str(self))
            time.sleep(a)
            print("The address is " + self.address)
            time.sleep(a)
            accept = input('Do you accept? (Yes/No):')
            if accept == 'Yes' or accept == 'yes':
                pizza_menu()
            elif accept == 'No' or accept == 'no':
                print("Joe: Fine I'll find someone else for the job.")
```

So to sum it up. When I execute the code it now prints out **Joe: He would like a Pineapple and Ham Pizza. The customer does not want the pizza to be sliced.** for each. customer even though every customer don't have Pineapple and Ham in their **customerdir** list. It's not printing out the other text that I put in the **repr**. Here is the full code on pastebin - https://pastebin.com/9ePT8Rj2

Thank you so much guys and sorry for the lost question and sorry if this is a bad question to ask.

Comment: Why are you calling `str` in that elif chain?

Comment: `str(self.customerdir == ['Pineapples', 'Ham', 'Not Sliced'])` would be either `'True'` or `'False'`, both of which are non-empty strings and therefore [truth-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: There must be more possible permutations of toppings and sliced or not other than those 3. You should try to think of a dynamic way to build the string rather than using `if/else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the problem is that you use `str(self.customerdir ==  ...)`.
This will result in the answer `'True'`, or `'False'` (note the string quotes), which will evaluate to True when you call `bool('True')` and `bool('False')`.

Also there are a lot of different representations that you could make for a Pizza. Which is similar to your customer class. So a good abstraction would be to create a  Pizza class per customer and build the representation logic into that class. Also please note the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`, called by `str()` and `repr()` respectively.

A Pizza class that could always represent your current order would look something like:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, toppings, sliced):
        self.toppings: set = set(toppings)   
        self.sliced = sliced
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.sliced:
            return f"{' and '.join(self.toppings)} Pizza. The customer does not want the pizza to be sliced."
        return f"{' and '.join(self.toppings)} Pizza that is sliced." 
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if len(other.toppings - self.toppings or self.sliced is not other.sliced:
            return False
        return True
```

Which can be used as:

```
>>> Pizza(toppings=['Pineapple', 'Ham'], sliced=False)
Pineapple and Ham Pizza that is sliced.
>>> Pizza(toppings=['Pineapple', 'Ham'], sliced=True)
Pineapple and Ham Pizza. The customer does not want the pizza to be sliced.
```

And for comparison:

```
>>> pizza_ham = Pizza(toppings=['Ham'], sliced=False)
>>> pizza_pepperoni = Pizza(toppings=['Pepperoni'], sliced=False)
>>> pizza_ham == pizza_pepperoni
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes sense now :)